# AngularJS : $compile with nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've created a simple directive that behaves like a collapsible panel.

The contents of this directive we add the item template that will be panels the ng-repeat template.
Everything works fine accessing each data source item but not when the template itself also have an ng-repeat.

Here's a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/7mhlO3GJTmFpyF1wrVYg

You can see that not even the static data child ng-repeat get compiled properly.

Here's the directive:

```
  app.directive('collapsible', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        srcData: "=ngModel"
      },
      link: function($scope, $element){

        // Extract the item template from the directive content
        var children = $element.children();

        // Wrap the item template with the repeater
        var template = angular.element('<div ng-repeat="item in srcData"></div>');
        template.append(children);

        var cfn = $compile(template);   // compile
        cfn($scope);                    // attach the scope
        $element.html(template);        // add it back to the directive content

        $element.on('click', 'h3 .button', function(e){
          e.stopPropagation();

          var $this = $(this);
          if($this.hasClass('close')){
              $scope.srcData.splice($this.scope().$index, 1);
              $scope.$apply();
          }
        });

        $element.on('click', 'h3', function(e){
          e.stopPropagation()

          var $this = $(this);
            $(this).next('div').toggle();
        });

      }
    };

  }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AH! Got it!!

So the problem is not with the nested ng-repeat but with the concept of template inside the directive.

I need to wrap the template with a `<script type="text/ng-template">` just to tell angular to leave it alone for the time being.

Here's the directive code now working:

```
  app.directive('collapsible', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        srcData: "=ngModel"
      },
      link: function($scope, $element){

        // Extract the item template from the directive content
        var children = $element.find('script').html();

        // Wrap the item template with the repeater
        var template = $('<div ng-repeat="item in srcData"></div>');
        template.append(children);

        var cfn = $compile(template);   // compile
        cfn($scope);                    // attach the scope
        $element.html(template);        // add it back to the directive content

        $element.on('click', 'h3 .button', function(e){
          e.stopPropagation();

          var $this = $(this);
          if($this.hasClass('close')){
              $scope.srcData.splice($this.scope().$index, 1);
              $scope.$apply();
          }
        });

        $element.on('click', 'h3', function(e){
          e.stopPropagation()

          var $this = $(this);
            $(this).next('div').toggle();
        });

      }
    };

  }]);
```

Comment: Can you show me the HTML? I do not understand how to wrap inner content with 'text/ng-template'